# Syncfusion grid row selection not working

Tags: c#, .net, syncfusion

I have recently upgraded the syncfusion grid version to 13.3460.0.7 from 5.102.1.0 in Application.

Issue: Shift + arrow keys rows selection feature has stopped working.

Below is the code snippet, I am using in constructor of sfGrid.cs class.

```
WantEnterKey = false;
WantKeys = false;

//this.Model.Options.ActivateCurrentCellBehavior = GridCellActivateAction.SelectAll;
this.Model.Options.AllowSelection = GridSelectionFlags.Any;
this.AllowSelection = GridSelectionFlags.Any;`
```

The feature is working in the older mentioned version with this code but not in new version.

Answer (score 0):

The `WantKeys` property is used to indicate whether key events should be suppressed or not. By setting this property to `false` key events will be disabled and the normal key navigation will not work, so I suggest you set it to `true` and see if that helps.